# SQLAlchemy with Aurora Serverless V2 PostgreSQL - many connections

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an AWS Serverless V2 database setup (postgresql) that is being accessed from a compute cluster. The cluster launches a large number of jobs (>1000) and each job independently puts/pulls some data from the database. The Serverless cluster is setup to autoscale from 2 to 32 units as needed.

The code being run by each cluster job is using SQLAlchemy (either the ORM or the core). I am setting up each database connection with a null pool and pessimistic disconnect handling (i.e., [pool_pre_ping=True](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic)). From my reading of the docs this should be handling disconnects due to being idle mid-connection.

Code is also written to access the DB, get the results, close the connection (to avoid idle connections), and then reopen the connection after processing (5-30 minutes). This is working well because once processing is completed, the new connections are staggered and the DB has scaled up.

My logs are showing the standard, all connections are taken error: `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser and rds_superuser connections` until the DB scales the available units high enough.

Questions:

- Should I be configuring the SQLAlchemy connection differently? It feels like an anti-pattern to put in a custom retry to grab a connection while waiting for the DB to scale the number of available units as this type of capability seems to be built into SQLAlchemy usually.
- Should I be using an [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) in front of the database? This also seems like an anti-pattern, adding a proxy in front of an autoscaling DB.

PG version is 10.

Comment: Is there some news on that topic as this is precisely what I am thinking about.